# Prove that for a martingale, any increasing stopping time is sufficient to be a local martingale

Tags: solution-verification, stochastic-processes, stopping-times, local-martingales

I would like to prove the following

> Let $(X_t)_t$ be a continuous martingale. Prove that any sequence of increasing stopping times (with values in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$) is sufficient to get a local martingale.

Here is my attempt : consider $\tau_n$ a sequence of increasing stopping time converging to $+\infty$ almost surely. We have for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $s>t$

$$
\mathbb{E}[1_{\tau_n>0}X_{s}^{\tau_n} | \mathcal{F}_t] =1_{\tau_n>0} \mathbb{E}[X_{s}^{\tau_n} | \mathcal{F}_t] = 1_{\tau_n>0}\left(\mathbb{E}[X_{s}^{\tau_n}1_{\tau_n>t} | \mathcal{F}_t] + X_{\tau_n}1_{\tau_n\leq t}\right)  
$$

We notice that for $t$ is a stopping time bounded by $\min(tau_n, s)\geq s$. Since $X_t$ is a martingale we can apply the stopping theorem for bounded stopping time to get

$$
1_{\tau_n>0}\left(\mathbb{E}[X_{s}^{\tau_n}1_{\tau_n>t} | \mathcal{F}_t] + X_{\tau_n}1_{\tau_n\leq t}\right) =1_{\tau_n>0}\left( X_t 1_{\tau_n>t}+ X_{\tau_n}1_{\tau_n\leq t}\right) =  X_{t}^{\tau_n} 
$$

I would like to know if this is correct please !

Thank you !